# Approximate the probability of choosing 4 of the most qualified people in a group of 15, in a committee of 10.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

From a group of 15 mathematics graduate school applicants, 10 are selected
at random. Let $P$ be the probability that 4 out of the 5 best applicants are included in the 10 selected. Which of the following statements is true?

(a) $0\leq P\leq\frac{1}{5}$

(b) $\frac{1}{5}<P\leq\frac{2}{5}$

(c) $\frac{2}{5}<P\leq\frac{3}{5}$

(d) $\frac{3}{5}<P\leq\frac{4}{5}$

(e) $\frac{4}{5}<P\leq 1$

I know that $P=\frac{C(5,4)*C(10,6)}{C(15,10)}$ but I'm not sure how to approximate it. Also should be noted that we do not have access to

Comment: It is not that hard to calculate the percentage, ESP if you only need to compare it to I/5

Answer (score 1):

To approximate, I would consider the following:

Tier the applicants into the five best, the five in the middle, and the five worst.

By the Pigeonhole Principle, at least one of the three tiers must contain four applicants. The probability for a single tier to contain four applicants is equally likely for each of the three tiers, so a reasonable approximation would be around $1/3$.

This would lead me to guess (if under time pressures) that the answer is (b).

Comment: +1 Nice approximation. The actual value is $\frac{50}{143} \approx 0.35$. It is higher than $\frac{1}{3}$ because it is possible for 2 tiers to contain more than 4 applicants.

Comment: Thanks; yes, that is the additional $\epsilon$, which one can see (after some amount of looking) will be pretty small.